# Automatically starting Celery from within Django app

Tags: linux, django, debian, celery, google-compute-engine

I am getting a Django 1.6 set up started on a Linux (Debian Whiskey) server on Google Compute Engine. I've got Celery 3.1 running in the background to help with some processes. When I start a new instance (using a snapshot I've created), I always need to start Celery. I am looking for a way to start Celery automatically on server-load. This is particularly helpful if the server decides to restart, as they seem to do now and then. To achieve this, I've edited the `rc.local` file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

It used to contain the following:

```
exit 0
[ -x /sbin/initctl ] && initctl emit --no-wait google-rc-local-has-run || true
```

I've edited the file such that it now reads:

```
cd /home/user/gce_app celery -A myapp.tasks --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info worker > output.log 2> errors.log &
exit 0
[ -x /sbin/initctl ] && initctl emit --no-wait google-rc-local-has-run || true
```

The directory:

```
/home/user/gce_app
```

is where my Django project resides and the directory I need to be in to start Celery. However, after restarting the instance, when I type in:

```
$ celery status
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
```

Opening the `errors.log` file, I see:

```
/etc/rc.local: 14: /etc/rc.local: celery: not found
```

Surely the `cd` at the start of that code string should address this? Is there a way (within the Django project itself) to start the Celery instance when the project is started to make the code more platform-independent and immune to inevitable OS updates?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a semicolon between your 'cd' and celery invocations.  Also, I suspect rc.local may not be searching your path, so you may need to give an absolute path to celery.  e.g.

`cd /home/user/gce_app; /usr/bin/celery ...`

Alternatively, you might look at using a [startup script from the GCE metadata](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript#example) to avoid needing to modify rc.local.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I'll try out including the semi-colon. The key here is to find a way to have celery started by the django app. I'm not keen on being locked into GCE or any other echo system - so if there's a way to tie the start up request to the django app itself that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using upstart this might help you:

```
description "runs celery"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

console log
env VENV='/srv/myvirtualenv'
env PROJECT='/srv/run/mydjangoproject'

exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' www-data -- /usr/bin/env PATH=$VENV:$PATH     $VENV/python $PROJECT/manage.py celeryd

respawn
respawn limit 10 5
```

Comment: careful with the respawn here. I would not use that, celery workers are designed to be robust. See these [celery init](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/) scripts.